# Is there a way to re-run AWS Security Hub CIS Benchmarks on demand?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm working on bringing a system into compliance with the various AWS Account CIS benchmarks (the CIS standard available via AWS Security Hub), and I'm wondering if there is any way to "re-run" the cis benchmarks to re-check each rule for compliance on demand. I've updated multiple configurations to comply with various rules that are currently at failed status, but there doesn't seem to be any way to force security hub to re-evaluate whether the account is currently in compliance or not. It shows that the rule was last updated about 10 hours ago, so I'm wondering if it automatically passively scans things and there isn't any way to trigger a manual re-run or re-check.

To clarify, I'm not asking about any individual rule. It appears that there is no way to manually re-run *any* rule. None of the documentation I've read on security hub seems to explicitly state that you cannot manually run the checks, but I have yet to find a way to do it.

The main documentation I've found on this topic seems to indicate that they are run automatically by default, so I'm basically just looking for confirmation that they can only be run automatically and there is no way to manually run it. This is the documentation that I'm referring to.

"Security Hub automatically runs continuous, account-level configuration and compliance checks based on industry standards and best practices, such as the Center for Internet Security (CIS) AWS Foundations Benchmarks. The result of these checks is provided as a compliance score, and specific accounts and resources that require attention are identified."

from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/what-is-securityhub.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put in a support ticket in AWS to ask for confirmation that there is no way to manually re-run the benchmarks on demand. They responded and confirmed that this is the case and it is only run automatically over time. This is the exact response.

"Thank you for contacting AWS Premium Support !  I understand that you would like to know is there a way to trigger the re-run of CIS benchmarks in Security Hub.

Unfortunately, there is no way to force it re-run again. As mentioned in our user guide, "Security Hub starts running the standards checks within 2 hours after the CIS AWS Foundations standard is enabled. The checks run again automatically within 12 hours from the latest check."

Answer (score 1):

After you enable a security standard, AWS Security Hub begins to run
all checks within two hours. Most checks begin to run within 25
minutes. Until a control completes its first run of checks, its status
is **No data**.

After the initial check, the schedule for each control can be either
periodic or change triggered.

- Periodic checks run automatically within 12 hours after the most
  recent run. You cannot change the periodicity.
- Change-triggered checks run when the associated resource changes
  state. Even if the resource does not change state, the updated at time
  for change-triggered checks is refreshed every 18 hours. This helps to
  indicate that the control is still enabled.

In general, Security Hub uses change-triggered rules whenever
possible. For a resource to use a change-triggered rule, it must
support AWS Config configuration items.

For a control that is based on a managed AWS Config rule, the control
description includes a link to the rule description in the AWS Config
Developer Guide. That description includes whether the rule is change
triggered or periodic.

Checks that use Security Hub custom Lambda functions are always
periodic.
[AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-standards-schedule.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open-source alternative which might be a more customisable for your needs https://github.com/cloudquery/cloudquery